# CSS scroll only overflow div, not the page

Tags: html, css

I have a DIV with `overflow:scroll` and when i scroll the div and it comes to the bottom, it starts scrolling the main page.

I want it **not** to scroll the main page - just the div.

Is this possible?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Owuu0.png

the image shows what i want NOT to happen

Comment: What do you mean by "and 'it' comes to the bottom"? Are you talking about the content of the div, or the scroll bar?

Comment: when i scroll the content of the div all the way to the bottom, it then starts scrolling the MAIN PAGE that it's on

Comment: Can you provide the code? Is the scroll bar for the entire page also visually moving as you scroll the div?

Comment: i posted a link to an image that explains it.

Comment: when you place your mouse inside the div and scroll, it scrolls the div. but when div reaches the bottom, it scrolls the whole page

Comment: If you're talking about scrolling with the mouse, then this is normal behavior for a scrollable div within another scrollable div. Why would you not want the main div to scroll down if the user continues to scroll?

Comment: I believe you're trying to stop the native window functionality. Are you only trying to scroll using the mousewheel? Does the div scroll if your mouse isn't over the div?

Comment: when the scroll reaches the bottom it moves the page so that other important buttons go out of view which is inconvenient to have to scroll back up, in case you "over scroll"

Comment: the div only scrolls when the mouse is hovering over it. i dont want to disable the main window scrolling completely - only when the mouse is hovering over another scrollable div

Comment: Yeah, so that's definitely the window functionality.  It scrolls any scrollable element until the end and the the next scrollable parent scrolls.  You could disable it with a js on hover function that blocks scrolling the window...  Hope that helps!  :)

Answer (score 2):

I wrote this little plugin for jQuery and am using it for a while now. It does what you want, but not in CSS. Maybe it is a solution anyway:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.privateScroll = function() {
        if ( this.length === 0 ) {
            return this;
        }
        this.bind('DOMMouseScroll mousewheel', function(e) {
                var delta = 0;
                if (typeof e.originalEvent.wheelDeltaY !== 'undefined') { // chrome, safari, opera
                    delta = e.originalEvent.wheelDeltaY;
                } else if (typeof e.originalEvent.wheelDelta !== 'undefined') { // ie
                    delta = e.originalEvent.wheelDelta;
                } else if (typeof e.originalEvent.detail != 'undefined') { // ff
                    delta = e.originalEvent.detail * -20;
                }
                if ( delta !== 0 ) {
                    $(this).scrollTop($(this).scrollTop() - delta );
                    e.preventDefault();
                    return false;
                }
        });
        return this;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Use like this:

```
jQuery('SELECTOR').privateScroll();
```

UPDATE: updated with a coworkers code to work with all browsers

Answer (score 0):

Try using `overflow: auto` instead of scroll and see if that works.

Comment: I'll have to see the code in order to provide diagnostic assistance.

Comment: theres a lot of code involved im pretty sure i can use js to solve this. i was just wondering if there was a quick CSS solution, but there probably isnt.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but I believe you might be able to use this jquery code to solve the issue.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('INNER DIV SELECTOR').hover(function() {
      $('INNER DIV SELECTOR').scroll(function(e) {
         e.stopPropagation();
      });
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the following sites for your reference:

http://manos.malihu.gr/tuts/custom-scrollbar-plugin/complete_examples.html

http://manos.malihu.gr/tuts/custom-scrollbar-plugin/nested_scrollbars_demo.html